# Incompatible pointer array 2D

Tags: c

Im new with C and i have to do a program for school.
I have 3 classes:
lab11.c(main)
procs.c
procs.h
Im getting this error everytime:

```
error: conflicting types for 'transposarMatriu'|
\procs.h|171|note: previous declaration of 'transposarMatriu' was here|
```

**My code (main):**

```
char matriu_ori[T_DIM_MAX][T_DIM_MAX];
char matriu_dst[T_DIM_MAX][T_DIM_MAX]
transposarMatriu(matriu_ori, *matriu_dst, mida, mida);
```

**Procs.h**

```
extern void transposarMatriu(char matriu_ori[][T_DIM_MAX], char matriu_dst[][T_DIM_MAX], int nfiles, int ncols);
```

**Procs.c**

```
void transposarMatriu(char matriu_ori[][T_DIM_MAX], char *matriu_dst[][T_DIM_MAX], int nfiles, int ncols) {
int c,d;
    for (c = 0; c < nfiles; c++) {
        for( d = 0 ; d < ncols ; d++ ) {
            *matriu_dst[d][c] = matriu_ori[c][d];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `transposarMatriu(matriu_ori, *matriu_dst, mida, mida);` --> `#include "Procs.h"`.

Comment: Function definition is different from the declaration. You can see the difference yourself.

Comment: Note: Filenames are usually case sensitive.  "I have 3 classes: lab11.c(main) procs.c procs.h " and `Procs.h`, `Procs.c` implies something amiss.  Use filename case consistently.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the discrepancy between the function definition in `procs.c` and its declaration in `procs.h`.

**Procs.h**

```
extern void transposarMatriu(char matriu_ori[][T_DIM_MAX], char matriu_dst[][T_DIM_MAX], int nfiles, int ncols);
```

The function signature must be identical, in this case is not, as you can see, in `procs.c` the second argument is of type `char*`, instead of `char` as in `procs.h`.

**Procs.c**

```
void transposarMatriu(char matriu_ori[][T_DIM_MAX], char *matriu_dst[][T_DIM_MAX], int nfiles, int ncols) {
...
```

Comment: You could always declare your functions using only the types to avoid confusion and improve readability, meaning that in `procs.h` you'll have `extern void trasposarMatriu(char,char,in,int);`

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: remove the asterisk in *lab11.c* and *procs.c*: `transposarMatriu([...] *matriu_dst [...])`

The function definition for `transposarMatriu` in *procs.c* declares `matriu_dst` to be of type array of arrays of pointers to char (`*matriu_dst[][]`) (see [C Right-Left Rule](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~ricko/rt_lt.rule.html) if you want to learn to decipher C declarations). Probably not what you intended and it's also a mismatch from the function declaration in *procs.h*.

I assume you intended `matriu_dst` to be "modifiable" like in call-by-reference, but there's no need to. Arrays are passed to functions by address, so they're "modifiable" by default.

By the same reasoning, there's no need to dereference `matriu_dst` in *main.c* (apply the `*` operator). In fact, doing so means you're passing the first element of the array to the function (an array of chars).